# Как использовать "изменитель" цветов в IntelliJ IDEA, Flutter?

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

Никаких кнопок нет, Нажимаю Enter ничего не происходит. Как его использовать?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы берете цвет из константы, которую не сможет поменять `ColorPicker`.

Попробуйте один из способов ниже:

```
final color = Color.fromRGBO(33, 236, 243, 1.0);
final color2 = Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 255, 63);
final color3 = Color(0xFF00AEFF);
```

После того, как вы создали цвет таким образом, слева также появится `ColorPicker`. Нажмите на него и покрутите цвета и вуаля, в вашем конструкторе будут меняться значения:)

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало